# add value to each month array

Tags: php, json, laravel-5

i have a set of branch which looping. i wanna add report section just like json output below..i'm using laravel as my json API..

branch result come from database.

```
$month  = array("January","February","March","April","May","June",
          "July","August","September","October","November","December");
```

this is my current code..stuck here

```
$result         = $branch;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($branch); $i++) {

      for ($col = 0; $col < count($month); $col++) {
        $result[$i]['report'] = ??
      }

    }

return(array("res"=>true,"branch"=>$result));
```

this is my expected output after process

```
{
"res": true,
"branch": [{
        "com_branch_id": 7,
        "report": {
            "January": {
                "totalSales": "400",
                "Profit": "1000"
            },
            "Febuary": {
                "totalSales": "400",
                "Profit": "1000"
            },
            "March": {
                "totalSales": "400",
                "Profit": "1000"
            },
            "April": {
                "totalSales": "400",
                "Profit": "1000"
            },
            "May": {
                "totalSales": "400",
                "Profit": "1000"
            },
            "Jun": {
                "totalSales": "400",
                "Profit": "1000"
            },
            "July": {
                "totalSales": "400",
                "Profit": "1000"
            },
            "August": {
                "totalSales": "400",
                "Profit": "1000"
            },
            "September": {
                "totalSales": "400",
                "Profit": "1000"
            },
            "October": {
                "totalSales": "400",
                "Profit": "1000"
            },
            "November": {
                "totalSales": "400",
                "Profit": "1000"
            },
            "December": {
                "totalSales": "400",
                "Profit": "1000"
            }
        }
    },

]
```

}

hope someone can help solved this problem..thanks..

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, I understand this is your first question, but it doesn't meet the standard quality expected, please read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to have some guidance.

Comment: Another good read on that is [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/2225619)

Answer (score 0):

You have not fully specified $branch structure but I believe code logic below may help clarify your problem.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($branch); $i++) {

    for ($col = 0; $col < count($month); $col++) {
         $result[$i]['report'][$month[$col]] = $branch[$i][$month[$col]];
    }

}
return(array("res"=>true,"branch"=>$result));
```

Comment: this is my branch ,  $branch   = DbConnectBranch::select('com_branch_name','com_branch_id')->where("com_branch_comId",$getApiKey->comId)->get();

Comment: error : Indirect modification of overloaded element of app\Http\Connection\DbConnectBranch has no effect